# Error when trying out GCP for Monte Carlo Methods

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, montecarlo, google-cloud-dataproc

I do not understand why I get the below error when I try to change the error logging for GCP.

> Error writing /etc/spark/conf/log4j.properties: No such file or directory

I am new to GCP and would like to learn how to use it but apparently, I keep getting errors no matter which tutorial I follow. Are there any good tutorials you can recommend?

Below is the tutorial I've tried and many more from the documentation of GCP.

[Monte Carlo Methods using Google Cloud Dataproc and Apache Spark](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/monte-carlo-methods-with-hadoop-spark)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: May you add command that you use to edit this file?

Comment: After you ssh into the master node, can you see the file using  $sudo nano /etc/spark/conf/log4j.properties  command?

Answer (score 1):

Dataproc doesn't have a default `log4j.properties`, but instead has a template (example) file at `/etc/spark/conf/log4j.properties.template`. You can copy the template and modify it:

```
sudo cp /etc/spark/conf/log4j.properties.template /etc/spark/conf/log4j.properties
```

For example, set `log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.Main=DEBUG`. Then, run `spark-shell` again.

Note that if you're submitting spark jobs using `gcloud` ("Next steps" in the tutorial), you can instead set log levels using `--driver-log-levels`: https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/guides/driver-output#configuring_logging